# Runtime Permissions code is not working for Fine location? android runtime location permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, location, runtime-permissions

I am trying to ask for permission from user but getting the black screen only and also lacking the app. Is their any wayout to update the same so I can get the permission from user.

MainActivity.this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
private ActionBar toolbar;
public static final int PERMISSION_FOR_INTERNET = 200;

DatabaseHelperClass dbClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.hide();
    checkforPermissions();
    CheckFirstTimeLoad();
    mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    CallFragment(new HomeFragment());
}


public void checkforPermissions(){
    String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permission[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permission[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            permission[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    } else {
        checkforPermissions();
    }
}
```

Please check the Manifest File. However, I added the permission code.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bhagatsoftinc.nearby">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_main_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDZOy6D7hVvtqu6iZy3hP395vZLSYbW1HI"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this

```
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

is a normal permission,
 you do not need to ask it at runtime just declare it in manifest , it
 will be granted automatically

**Now here is the example code to ask location permissions**

> Step 1:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

> Step 2:-

in `onCreate()` do this

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// rest of the code here
    checkAndroidVersion();
}
```

> Step 3:-

this method `checkAndroidVersion();`

```
public void checkAndroidVersion() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
              // do your work here
            } else
            {
            }

        } else {

            // do your work here
        }

    }
```

> Step 4:-

this method

> checkAndRequestPermissions()

```
public boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

        int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

> Step 5:-

Handle `onRequestPermission()` method

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("in main on request", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("in main on request", "location services permission granted");
                        // do your work here
                    } else {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                            showDialogOK("Location services  services are required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }



 public void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```